# How to model if a company is mentioned in a review (volume) and how it is mentioned (valence)?

Tags: proportion, count-data, zero-inflation, tobit-regression

I am working with social media data of Brand A and would like to model what features of posts of Brand A are linked to if a competitor (Brand B) is mentioned in the comments of different posts of Brand A.

Is it possible to model in a single model:

- how often Brand B is mentioned in the comments of a post of Brand A as the
  DV (count variable)
- as a next step, model the share of positive comments of all comments where Brand B is mentioned as a second, sequential DV (proportion variable between 0 and 100)

Assume Brand A has 10,000 posts, each with on average of 10 comments. Brand B is mentioned in about 5% of the posts. 33% of these mentions are positive on average (sometimes all are positive, sometimes none).

How would I sequentially model (a) to how many mentions of Brand B did the content features of the post of Brand A lead and (b) how large is the share of positive mentions of Brand B?

I was thinking of a combination of a hurdle model or Tobit regression, but I struggle conceptually how to best approach this.

Thank you!